# Devil? (Mc) In high school fighting experimented-on people

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga a while back.

Basically this Devil (possibly) woke up from a coma, or just a really long sleep. Mf his friend who serves/worships/follows him is now a high school principal and while he’s in the school I remember him having this really fancy name because some point these like twins who are like nobles(?) were talking about it.

The main character lives with his friend (the one who serves him) and also they fight off people who were experimented on.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Is the principal of the school male or female?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Parts of this match [*Welcome to Demon School! Iruma-kun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welcome_to_Demon_School!_Iruma-kun)

> The story follows Iruma Suzuki, a 14-year-old human boy, who is sold to a demon by his lazy, selfish and neglectful parents. The demon, known as Sullivan, takes Iruma to the Demon World and officially adopts him as his grandson. He enrolls Iruma in the Babyls School for Demons where he is the headmaster and where Iruma quickly befriends the demons Alice Asmodeus and Clara Valac. However, Sullivan tells Iruma to never reveal that he is human since he will be eaten if anyone finds out. Iruma then vows to blend in during his time in the demon world, although he only stands out because of all the situations and adventures that arise. By his second year Iruma turns 15 years old.

Iruma is not a demon, but the other people in the school are. Sullivan is not his servant, but his guardian. He does have at least one teacher who serves him, his homeroom teacher, Kalego, who he accidentally summoned as a familiar. I thought I had a better match for fighting people who were experimented on, but with a bit more research, it seems Balam's experiments were rumors, not actuality.

Answer (score 1):

Noblesse hes a vampire though but he does fight altered humans

Noblesse is of a strong aristocrat - He is beginning to become accustomed to today's world, and has woken up within an abandoned building in South Korea. He goes into a school where he meets with his true servant Frankenstein. Into Ye Ran high school, Rai registers with Frankenstein's help, and unwittingly befriends Shin Woo - an athletic teen, Ik Han - Yuna, a computer geek - some others, and Shin Woo's puppy love. Noblesse follows the frequently dangerous experiences against a secret organization of the group while uncovering Rai's past

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noblesse_(manhwa)